# Clone / Copy one specific branch in a repository in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a branch `Predictive_Frame_Animals` which is not the default branch `main`, how can i copy  the `Predictive_Frame_Animals` branch to a new branch, which is called `Predictive_Frame_Lions`.

When I try to fork it,
I can only fork the default branch or all branches into a new repository, that is not what I want.

The repository should stay the same, I only want to create a new branch in it , which is a copy of the exisiting branch `Predictive_Frame_Animals`. How can I do that in Azure Dev Ops or in a command line in visual studio code?

Comment: Hang on a second. Let's make sure you're using the correct terminology. A fork is a **complete copy of a repository**, including **all branches**. Are you trying to create a fork of the repository, or create a new branch in an existing repository? These are *very different* things.

Comment: I try to copy only one branch, then fork is the wrong wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the console you should

1. First `git checkout Predictive_Frame_Animals`
2. Create a new branch  `git checkout -b Predictive_Frame_Lions Predictive_Frame_Animals`

And when you create a new branch in Azure DevOps you can select base branch

[image]